# What was Jeroboam's lineage?

Tags: sources-mekorot, navi-prophets, melachim-kings-book-of

Are there any sources describing Jeroboam's ancestry?

in particular, is he an Ephraimite or an Ephrathite?

Comment: Which one? Yerovam ben Yoash or Yerovom ben Nevat?

Comment: @Dov Most like the latter as the former's lineage is spelled out pretty clearly in the Tanakh.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking about Yerovam ben Nevat, there are several sources that show he was indeed from the tribe of Ephraim.

The **[Yerushalmi Sanhedrin 10:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Sanhedrin.10.2.27?vhe=The_Jerusalem_Talmud,_edition_by_Heinrich_W._Guggenheimer._Berlin,_De_Gruyter,_1999-2015&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)** writes explicitly:

> אֶפְרַיִם מָע֣וֹז רֹאשִׁ֑י זֶי יָרָבְעַם בֶּן נְבָט אֶפְרָתִי
>
> "Ephraim my chief stronghold" ([Tehillim 60:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.60.9?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi)) - that is Yerovam ben Nevat the Ephraimite.

Also refer to [Sanhedrin 104b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.104b.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) for the same point -  אפרים מעוז ראשי זה ירבעם דקאתי מאפרים

It is also spelled out quite clearly in numerous examples:

[Rabbinu Bachya on Bamidbar 2:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Rabbeinu_Bahya%2C_Bamidbar.2.2.8?vhe=Midrash_Rabbeinu_Bachya_%5Bben_Asher%5D._Warsaw,_1878&lang=bi) says expressly:

> ידעת כי ירבעם חטא והחטיא את הרבים והוא היה משבט אפרים
>
> You are aware that Yerovam both sinned himself and caused the whole people to sin. He was of the tribe of Ephraim.

See also [Pesikta Rabbosi 3:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesikta_Rabbati.3.1?vhe=OYW&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

Finally, the Midrash in [Eicha Rabbah](https://www.sefaria.org/Eichah_Rabbah%2C_Petichta.6?lang=bi) writes:

> רַבִּי אַבָּהוּ בְּשֵׁם רַבִּי יוֹסֵי בַּר חֲנִינָא פָּתַח (הושע ה, ט): אֶפְרַיִם לְשַׁמָּה תִהְיֶה
>
> Rabbi Avahu in the name of Rabbi Yosi son of Chaninah began: "Ephraim will be as a desolation" ([Hoshea 5:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Hosea.5.9?lang=bi)).

The [Matnos Kehuna](https://www.sefaria.org/Matnot_Kehunah_on_Eichah_Rabbah%2C_Petichta.6.2?lang=bi) there explains on this quote:

> אפרים. עשרת השבטים נקראו בשם אפרים על שם שהמליכו עליהם ירבעם משבט אפרים
>
> Ephraim - 10 tribes were called with the name Ephraim after the name that was ruled by Yerovam from the tribe of Ephraim.